# Triple Boot 2010 Macbook Pro with Dual Drive

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, unix, dual-boot

I have a 2010 Macbook pro running Mavericks and Windows 7 on a 250gb SSD. I just removed the cd drive and installed my old 250 gb hard drive. So now I have two drives. I would like to make the hard drive purely for a linux distribution.

How should I go about doing this?

Some things to note/ consider:
1.   I have no CD drive so I would like to boot up from a USB.
2.   I read that Mavericks has issues with dual booting. So I can't trust many sources?
3.   What file format should I erase the new drive to.
4.   Also should I use rEFInd for booting purposes?
5.   I am aware there are plety of tutorials that walk you through installing linux but I want to have
     A second hard drive JUST for linux.

My current plan is:
Reformat drive with Mac OS Extended (journalized).... Install rEFInd.... Burn ubuntu ISO to flash drive... install ubuntu though rEFInd?

I have no clue if this is at all correct

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a lot of pain (and time) by using virtual machines. VMware Fusion is $50 and lets you run multiple Mac OS, multiple Windows OS, linux, DOS etc. all at the same time.

I do web development, so I need to use Internet Exploder in 4 different versions. I can't do that on one boot, but I can have 3 instances of windows open at once. My job would take a LOT longer if I had to multi-boot my machine.

Comment: This is an answer to an old question. But may help newcomers having the same problem.
Thank you for your attempt to help.